# MySql exported data partially and I can't import it back

Tags: php, mysql

So I exported a part of data from a table using the command:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','database');
$sql = "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'data.sql' FROM table WHERE PID<50";
mysqli_query($con, $sql);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

It exported successfully, I got a 'data.sql' file in my directory and the content is exactly what I chose(data with PID from 1 to 49). However whenever I tried to import it back using phpmyadmin into a new table with same name, same columns, in a different database, it keeps showing error

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

Full Error message:

SQL query:

2   Austin Benedict Trisanto    002 240000  2015-07-01  1970-01-01  \N  20000   4

3   Faylisha Syema  001 120000  2015-07-01  \N  \N  0   2

4   Tiara Aurellia Prasetyo 003 230000  2015-07-01  1970-01-01  \N  0   2

5   Darrell Maximilian Dirgantara   004 210000  2015-07-01  1970-01-01  \N  0   2

6   mikaela reva calista    005 210000  2015-07-01  1970-01-01  \N  0   2

7   Gisella Joycelin Tian Sibarani  006 220000  2015-07-01  1970-01-01  \N  15000   3

8   Putu Pooja Sita Laticia 007 230000  2015-07-01  1970-01-01  \N  0   2

9   Mikhael Lucius Arkananta Prama  008 230000  2015-07-01  1970-01-01  \N  0   2

MySQL said: Documentation

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '2    Austin Benedict Trisanto    002    240000    2015-07-01    1970-01-01    \N    20000    4

3    Faylish' at line 1

What exactly could be going wrong ? or what I am doing wrong ? should I import it back using php too ?

All answers are greatly welcomed. Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you post some of the sql?

Comment: Can you show your export command? Because in the code above its only select. You must use dump to dump it to sql file.

Comment: Your error message tells you _exactly_ where the error is. You just truncated it exactly _before_ the bit where it gets interesting. So 1. please post the start of that exported file, 2. post the _full_ error message and 3. tell _how_ you tried to import the data.

Comment: @arkascha full error message posted above

Comment: Why not to use the built in Export function to export the rows?

Comment: @JohnRoca that is how I exported, using SELECT...INTO OUTFILE

Comment: So you have your answer, right? What you try to import is not SQL. So how is an SQL server meant to make sense of that data? You have to either "dump" the data using a tool like `mysql_dump` which creates sql statements that can be re-imported, or you need to use a tool that allows you to import `csv` like data.

Comment: and there is the problem... you need to ensure that you export the data in a format that can be imported back into mysql rather than just a dump of the data in tab delimited form ( looks like tab delimited ) ~ use the export function within phpmyadmin to export  from one db

Comment: Well so using SELECT... INTO OUTFILE does produce importable sql file ?

Comment: @Charas You must use sql dump. Because there is no insert command in your dump.sql. You are inserting a none sql file. Here is good link for a tutorial for you [Backup and Restore MySQL Database Using mysqldump] (http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/backup-and-restore-mysql-database-using-mysqldump/)

Comment: @Chars That is correct when you say "Well so using SELECT... INTO OUTFILE will not produce importable sql file".

Answer (score 0):

What you have for import isn't in SQL format.

Additionally, I've never had much luck running it through `PHP` and `phpMyAdmin`.

I am only answering this in this fashion, because it is my preferred method of backing up, and restoring databases.

**NOTE** You have to have shell access for this method.

To **back up** the database.  Use the following:

```
$ mysqldump -u UserName -p PassWord your_database > /directory/backup_file.sql
```

Or You can use `mysql` `cli` to output a query:

```
$ mysql -e "select * from yourTable" -u userName -p passWord YourDataBase > /directory/backup_file.sql
```

To **import** your file to your new db:

```
$ mysql -u userName -p passWord newDatabase < /directory/backup_file.sql
```

With the import, you won't have to specify the table, as that will be stored in the `sql` file.

Might not be what you are hoping for, but this is  a valid alternative to using PHP to do this.  And in fact it's the preferred method as it is quick, easy, reliable and effective.  There is no code except for your `SQL` query that is needed.  Less code = Less chance of breaking.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now that is backing up the whole database right ? How do I back up only some rows from a table inside a database ?

Comment: The second method  I have in my answer :-) `$ mysql -e "select * from yourTable" `

Comment: I tried using powershell and cmd, both keeps getting the same error: ERROR 1049(42000): unknown database, do you have any idea why is my database did not get read ?

Comment: I'm not sure about your setup.. It may work to `yourDatabase.yourTable` do define the DB

Comment: well i am using windows 8, and when i run mysqlshow, it does now show all my db, any idea why ?

Comment: ?  Sounds like you have more of an issue to deal with.. Maybe you have multiple mysql severs running (yes this is possible, unfortunately)